# Persisting data within the Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot

I am creating a small application using Spring Boot, this application allows users to store XML templates which can be reused in various scenarios.

The XML templates are small and will be less that 100 lines each, also there will not be more than 20 templates. I don't want to use a separate database to store this small information.

Also I don't want to store this information in memory as I want to retain the data when the app is restarted.

What is the suggested option to store this kind of data within the Spring Boot app itself without using an external database ?

Comment: Use H2 database with in memory db or save it on local disk. Or you can go for plain old write file to disk and just write a file to the disk and have another file to keep track of meta information for your writes. But this will help you only if you can ensure you have access to servers and they in turn are not volatile. Spring boot as such has not out of box solution for this other than embedded database

Answer (score 0):

Use H2 database with in memory db or save it on local disk. Or you can go for plain old write file to disk and just write a file to the disk and have another file to keep track of meta information for your writes. But this will help you only if you can ensure you have access to servers and they in turn are not volatile. Spring boot as such has not out of box solution for this other than embedded database